Met an error "mdframed.sty: error: 76: File `zref-abspage.sty' not found. \RequirePackage"
Met an error "mdframed.sty: error: 76: File `zref-abspage.sty' not found. \RequirePackage". Do I need to install the zref package?

Please provide more details, what you provided are not enough

mdframed.sty line 75: \RequirePackage{zref-abspage}. So yes. Though nowadays, I'd recommend using tcolorbox instead

@MadyYuvi not really clear what further details are required here? unless you mean that more details might reveal the OP doesn't really need mdframed?

@cfr actually the OP provided mdframed.sty: error: 76: File zref-abspage.sty not found. \RequirePackage, and nothing details was provided, e.g., class file name and other used supporting packages, etc. So only I asked

@MadyYuvi usually you'd be right. I only meant that, in this specific case, the error is pretty self-explanatory. we don't really need to know the class etc. however, if we did know the class, the OP might get a more useful answer e.g. we might be able to say that zref will cause issues with that class or something. but in terms of just addressing this error, the fix is straightforward, it seems to me. or am I missing something?

@cfr Please excuse, you people are Guru in LaTeX, but myself still one of a beginner only, you never missed any thing, I only misunderstood your comment, and I am not an expert in English too :-(

@MadyYuvi nothing to excuse. believe me, I am no guru! and I miss obvious things all the time. (and I am not even trying to work in another language ....)

If you want to use the mdframed package then, yes, you need to install zref since mdframed.sty includes the line
\RequirePackage{zref-abspage}

and zref-abspage.sty is part of the zref package.
This is what the error message LaTeX provided is telling you. If you compile interactively and press h at the prompt, you may get a bit more information.

Thanks. Can the tex platform or MiKex install the package automatically?

@Carl TeX can't. miktex can, if configured to do so. I've never used miktex, so I can't tell you how to do it, but that is one of the 'selling points' of miktex. note that I don't know what the status of this feature is on platforms where miktex is newer, but it is definitely a thing on windows. however, if you are getting that error, then I assume on-the-fly installation is either not configured or not working for you, since miktex should install the package if your document requires it. (it might ask you first or something - like I say, i don't know the details.)
